# ejs + nodejs - compare two variables doesn't work

Tags: node.js, ejs

I pass two variables during rendering in nodejs. Let's say they're templates & treeInfo.

In template.ejs I have.

```
        <% for(var i=0; i<templates.length; i++) {%>
          <%= templates[i]._id %> = <%= treeInfo.owner[0] %><br>
          <% if (templates[i]._id == treeInfo.owner) { %>
              ok
          <% } %>
        <% } %>
```

So actually if == doesn't work as expected. Here's the output.

59519779f36d284c166f9bea = 5941789e36593262bed9256b

5941789e36593262bed9256b = 5941789e36593262bed9256b

So it doesn't compare them the right way. If I just replace treeInfo.owner with something like '5941789e36593262bed9256b', it does work fine.

I assume ejs doesn't support variables comparation?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I just see that you do the assignment by doing templates[i]._id = treeInfo.owner[0]. But you compare it with just treeInfo.owner. Shouldn't it be 'if (templates[i]._id == treeInfo.owner[0])'. The comparison is being done with value to object.

Comment: Hi Duane, either way doesn't work :/

Comment: Eventually I did JSON.stringify(templates[i]._id) == JSON.stringify(treeInfo.owner[0]) and now it works fine.

Thanks !

Comment: Cool. Yeah I was just informing you about the typo where u did not include treeInfo.owner[0] and instead had the comparison done against treeInfo.owner. Guess its corrected in the JSON.stringify solution.

Answer (score 1):

Variable type can't understand.That's why toString() is required.

```
<% for(var i=0; i<templates.length; i++) {%>
  <%= templates[i]._id %> = <%= treeInfo.owner[0] %><br>
  <% if (templates[i]._id.toString() == treeInfo.owner.toString()) { %>
         __append('Hello World');
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare two objects / variables in EJS, as well as in nodejs

```js
if(user1.equals(user2))
{
console.log("Both are equal");
}
```